# Mongo - Does index use full scan?

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing, mongodb-query

I hunt for slow queries in mongo using db.currentOp() command.

Usually it shows planSummary for queries that use indexes.

This is a report for one of them:

[image]
       http://kagda.ru/i/9b016249b683_31-12-2018-13:57:00_9b01.png

Plan field is missing. Does this mean that this query uses full scan?

Comment: seen that myself. The only thing i can think of is that it hangs on a plan selection stage. Probably some index not fully loaded in order to decide if it will be used or not. Don't know how to troubleshoot it though.